# How can I remove google chrome cookies

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cookies

I'm trying to remove cookies of chrome browser. Firstly I declared the path

```
string chromeLocation1 = "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName.ToString() + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Local Storage";
```

When I try to run my remove code "The file is in use by another program or user" error appears. So I tried to kill `chrome.exe`'s proccess

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome.exe"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

But now it gives me "Access Denied" error even I run it as administrator. What should I do to remove these cookies?

Comment: Is it finding the processes in `Process.GetProcessByName("chrome.exe")`  ?  I thought that you had to search without the extension (i.e. `Process.GetProcessByName("chrome")`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete all cookies with [selenium framework](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium).

1) Install selenium framework - `Selenium WebDriver` and `Selenium WebDriver Support Classes` (the easiest way to do this is by using NuGet)

[image: NuGet]

2) Use the following code to delete all cookies:

```
var chromeUserData = "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
var chromeAdvancedSettings = "chrome://settings/clearBrowserData";
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--lang=en");
options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + chromeUserData);
options.LeaveBrowserRunning = false;
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(chromeAdvancedSettings);

var frame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='chrome://settings-frame/clearBrowserData']"));
var frameDriver = driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
var dropDown = new SelectElement(frameDriver.FindElement(By.Id("clear-browser-data-time-period")));
dropDown.SelectByIndex(4);
var elm = driver.FindElement(By.Id("delete-cookies-checkbox"));
if (!elm.Selected) elm.Click();
elm = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='clear-browser-data-commit']"));
elm.Click();
var waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
waiter.Until(wd => wd.Url.StartsWith("chrome://settings"));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://newtab");
```

[[Selenium documentation]](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki)

Comment: I installed it but it says "ChromeDriver" namespace not found

Comment: @JayGatsby try using this namespace: `using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;`

Comment: code works without error but when I execute it a dos screen appears with this text and cookies are not deleted "Starting ChromeDriver 2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29) on
port 22774
Only local connections are allowed.
"

Comment: @JayGatsby check my answer again :)

Comment: Be careful with this approach. It can delete cookies you do not want to delete because you cannot choose domains in this Chrome tab. You may be logged out from sites you do  not want to.

Answer (score 0):

if You want to delete your browser all data using C# language then you can delete each browser history,cookies etc (all data) using different code.

Here i write some code for deleting all data of Internet explorer

1-- Delete all data/History of Internet Explorer in a button click (Window Form application or WPF application)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //For internet explorer
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");

        }
```

2--- Now the importent browser Google Chrome (the mystery because everyone try to delete all history of it using SQLite but it wrong). Dont use SQLite database because google chrome Hold all data( History, Cookies, and etc) in following location

C:\Users\UserName(Your PC Name)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

just delete all 'User Data' Folder or all the folders and files within it. then you will see your all history and cookies clear.

Following is the code for it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //For internet explorer
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");

            // for Google Chrome.
            string rootDrive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory); // for getting primary drive 
            string userName = Environment.UserName; // for getting user name

              // first close all the extension of chrome (close all the chrome browser which are opened)

            try
            {
                Process[] Path1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
                foreach (Process p in Path1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        p.Kill();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    p.WaitForExit();
                    p.Dispose();
                }


                System.IO.DirectoryInfo downloadedMessageInfo = new DirectoryInfo(rootDrive + "Users\\"+userName+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");


                try
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo file in downloadedMessageInfo.GetFiles())
                    {
                        file.Delete();
                    }
                }
                catch { }

                try
                {
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in downloadedMessageInfo.GetDirectories())
                    {
                        dir.Delete(true);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
                label1.Text = " History Deleted successfully.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the cookies history and cache by following the below console application

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111667/9377382