# How can I delete google chrome cookies with selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, cookies

I'm trying delete all google chrome cookies. I'm using this code which I found it on selenium's website:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
```

But when I execute it a dos page appears with this text

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29) on
port 25398
Only local connections are allowed.
```

And google chrome starting. What did I miss? How can I delete stored cookies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove google chrome cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364152/how-can-i-remove-google-chrome-cookies)

Answer (score 6):

The method `DeleteAllCookies();` will delete all the cookies for the current domain  [[Handling Cookies in Webdriver]](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-cookies-in-selenium-webdriver).

If you want to delete all cookies for all domain you should use solution from Chrome settings "Clear browsing data".

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364624/1410998) you have example of usage.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome supports [DevTools Protocol commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) like `Network.clearBrowserCookies` that you can call remotely that will delete cookies for **all domains**. Selenium does not support this because it's not part [of the standard](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver) and it doesn't work in other browsers than Chrome.

However, you can add support for these commands by patching Selenium's supported commands like this:

```
send_command = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
driver.command_executor._commands['SEND_COMMAND'] = send_command
```

Now you can call any DevTools Protocol command like

```
driver.execute('SEND_COMMAND', dict(cmd='Network.clearBrowserCookies', params={}))
```

This deletes all cookies for all domains.