# how to delete all google chrome cookies using powershell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, cookies

Firstly, I am not getting the specific file where the google chrome store cookies in.
Secondly, I may think that it store in `google\chrome\User Data\Default` in this path i found cookies name file. I delete the file but still google chrome contains the cookies in their browser.
So, what is the way to delete the cookies file using `Powershell` so it won't appear the same cookies in browser.

Comment: One way is to use Selenium, as this [C# sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364624) demonstrates. Why are you deleting the cookies anyway? Depending on what's the root need, maybe there's better a way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Totally agree with your suggestion. But I need to use PowerShell. Is there any way to perform the same?

Comment: Why Powershell only? And how come the proposed solution is too long? It seems there are hidden constraints, and that heavily hints to a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Please edit your question and more details.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here's my attempt to clearup Chrome history (including cookies)

```
function Clear-ChromeHistory {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Removes Google Chrome history entries.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Removes Google Chrome history entries.
    .NOTES
        Author: Theo Ros
    .PARAMETER DaysToKeep
        Specifies the number of days to keep history. Everything older that
        the given number of days (as seen from now) will be removed.
        Defaults to 7
    .PARAMETER Recommended
        This is a shorthand switch. When set, all ArchivedHistory, BrowsingHistory,
        Cookies, Favicons, MediaData and TemporaryFiles will be cleared.
        FormData, Passwords and TopSites will be left alone.
    .PARAMETER All
        This is a shorthand switch. When set, ALL history items will be cleared.
    .PARAMETER ArchivedHistory
        When set, Archived History (BrowsingHistory older than 90 days) will be removed.
    .PARAMETER BrowsingHistory
        When set, History and History-journal and Visited Links will be removed.
    .PARAMETER Cookies
        When set, Cookies and Cookies-journal will be removed.
    .PARAMETER Favicons
        When set, Favicons and Favicons-journal will be removed.
    .PARAMETER Passwords
        When set, Login Data and Login Data-journal will be removed.
    .PARAMETER MediaData
        When set, the Media Cache will be emptied.
    .PARAMETER TemporaryFiles
        When set, the Temporary Cache will be emptied.
    .PARAMETER TopSites
        When set, Top Sites and Top Sites-journal will be removed.
    .PARAMETER FormData
        When set, Web Data en Web Data-journal (among others Autocomplete) will be removed.
    .EXAMPLE
        Clear-ChromeHistory -Recommended -DaysToKeep 14
        Will remove all Recommended items older than 14 days.
    .EXAMPLE
        Clear-ChromeHistory -Cookies -DaysToKeep 0
        Will remove all cookies.
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Recommended', ConfirmImpact = 'None')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
        [int] $DaysToKeep = 7,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Recommended')]
        [switch] $Recommended,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByAll')]
        [switch] $All,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $ArchivedHistory,  # Archived History (BrowsingHistory older than 90 days)
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $BrowsingHistory,  # file: History and History-journal and Visited Links
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $Cookies,          # file: Cookies and Cookies-journal
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $Favicons,         # file: Favicons and Favicons-journal
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $Passwords,        # file: Login Data and Login Data-journal
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $MediaData,        # folder: Media Cache
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $TemporaryFiles,   # folder: Cache
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $TopSites,         # file: Top Sites and Top Sites-journal
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByItem')]
        [switch] $FormData          # file: Web Data en Web Data-journal (among others Autocomplete)
    )

    if (Get-Process -Name chrome -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Warning ("Chrome process(es) are still running. Please close all before clearing the history.`r`n" +
                       "Use Get-Process -Name chrome -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue")
        return
    }

    $path = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Error "Chrome history path '$path' not found"
        return
    }

    if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Recommended') {
        # remove all these:
        $ArchivedHistory = $BrowsingHistory = $Cookies = $Favicons = $MediaData = $TemporaryFiles = $true
        # but leave these intact:$FormData = $Passwords = $TopSites
         = $false
    }

    $msg = @()
    $items = @()
    if ($ArchivedHistory -or $All) { $items += "Archived History*"             ; $msg += "Archived History" }
    if ($BrowsingHistory -or $All) { $items += @("History*", "Visited Links*") ; $msg += @("History", "Visited Links") }
    if ($Cookies -or $All)         { $items += "Cookies*"                      ; $msg += "Cookies" }
    if ($Favicons -or $All)        { $items += "Favicons*"                     ; $msg += "Favicons" }
    if ($FormData -or $All)        { $items += "Web Data*"                     ; $msg += "Form Data" }
    if ($MediaData -or $All)       { $items += "Media Cache*"                  ; $msg += "Media Cache" }
    if ($Passwords -or $All)       { $items += "Login Data*"                   ; $msg += "Passwords" }
    if ($TemporaryFiles -or $All)  { $items += "Cache*"                        ; $msg += "Temporary Files Cache" }
    if ($TopSites -or $All)        { $items += "Top Sites*"                    ; $msg += "Top Sites" }

    $oldErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    $refdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-([Math]::Abs($DaysToKeep)))
    $allItems = @()
    if ($items.Length) {
        $allItems += $items | ForEach-Object {
            $name = $_
            Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { ($_.CreationTime -lt $refdate) -and $_.Name -like $name }
        }
    }

    if ($allItems.Length) {
        # type the bullet character with Alt-7
        $join = "`r`n         • "
        $msg = ($msg | Sort-Object) -join $join
        Write-Verbose ("$($MyInvocation.MyCommand):$join$msg")

        $allItems | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Recurse }
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand): Nothing selected or older than $($refdate.ToString()) found"
    }
    $ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorActionPreference
}
```

To just remove cookies and nothing else, use it like so:

```
Clear-ChromeHistory -DaysToKeep 1 -Cookies -Verbose
```

However, there are a lot more switches with which you can remove other Chrome data aswell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This method is too long. I want a short method to perform the query to remove cookies. Do you know any?

Comment: One way of shortening the *calling* of the function is to store it as a Powershell module in your Modules path. Let's say you call the module "CleanChrome". Create a folder called `CleanChrome` in your modules path. Next save the function in there as a file caled `CleanChrome.psm1`. Then all you have to do is use it with just this code `Import-Module CleanChrome; Clear-ChromeHistory -DaysToKeep 0 -Cookies` without ever having to look at the function itself. Another way of course it to cut away all functionality you do not need and just keep the cookies stuff..

Comment: The second option is cutting away everything but the code for deleting cookies. You can end-up simply doing `$path = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"; gci $path -Recurse -Force | ? {$_.Name -like 'Cookies*'} | % {ri $_.FullName -Force -Recurse}`. Of course, this leaves you without any error handling.. Personally, I would advise to use the `Module` option above and not simply go for the shortest code possible (if only for learning Powershell coding)