# Is there a delete_all_cookies() for ALL domains in Selenium / Chrome?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Python to automate Chrome with Selenium and Chromedriver. I specify a `user-data-dir` so that the browser has a persistent cache. The problem then is that it also persists cookies and I'd like to delete them *prior* to each automation run. The only reliable way I have found to do this is to delete all the records from the SQLite3 database `$USER_DATA_DIR/Default/Cookies`.

There is a method in Selenium webdrivers called `delete_all_cookies()` but it only removes cookies for the domain of the current URL!

Is there a better method or perhaps a command I can send ChromeDriver that will clear *all* cookies? Alternatively, is there a setting I can configure which will cause Chrome to remove cookies when it exits and/or starts up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome supports [DevTools Protocol commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) like `Network.clearBrowserCookies` that you can call remotely.  Selenium does not have an interface for this because it's not part of any standard.

However, you can add support for these commands by patching Selenium's supported commands like this:

```
send_command = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
driver.command_executor._commands['SEND_COMMAND'] = send_command
```

Now you can call any DevTools Protocol command like

```
driver.execute('SEND_COMMAND', dict(cmd='Network.clearBrowserCookies', params={}))
```

This deletes all cookies for all domains.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around:

You can use Selenium to browse "chrome://settings/clearBrowserData" and use that page to delete cookies as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364624/2546759.

The pitfall is that this page layout sometime changes between chrome versions.

Comment: I had tried some UI automation on the Chrome preferences but I didn't have a lot of luck, perhaps because I am also running this in XVFB? This particular answer seems to reference Windows-specific stuff too and the automation I'm writing runs on Mac, Linux / Docker, and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Run Chrome using `incognito mode` or private browsing

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver= webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: The downside of incognito mode is you're giving up not only cookies but also cached items. At least, that has been my experience in testing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the accepted answer, Python Selenium Chromium WebDriver now has `driver.execute_cdp_cmd()` method:

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.clearBrowserCookies', {})
```