# How to automatically clear specific cookies from Chrome programatically

Tags: c#, python-3.x, google-chrome

I am trying to delete specific cookies from google Chrome, but I do not want to delete all cookies, only cookies from a specific domain.

I want to be able to do this while Chrome is still running, similar to how its own clear browsing history works.

I understand that Chrome keeps the cookies in the default profile, in what I believe to be an sqlite3 file if I am not mistaken.

I have tried using macros to just click the clear cookies button in Chrome but this obviously locks up the current user from doing anything else. I actually wanted to do this programatically via Python or C# if necessary.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364152/how-can-i-remove-google-chrome-cookies) answer may be helpful for you.

Comment: @ikerbera I have actually tried using Selenium with Python, and while it seems to delete the cookies, it somehow is making the browser loading a lot more slowly, I do believe that the site I am working with is using cookies as a request control method. I am not abusing the site, I am keeping a delay of around 5 seconds between requests.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following C# console application for clearing the code in browser application.

History/cookies/cache are stored as physical files in particular directory.

Following clears the data for chrome for other browsers you can search where data is being stored and can erase them accordingly.

```
    public void getandclear()
    {
        string userName = Environment.UserName; 
        string[] chromedata = { "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History"
                               ,"C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History Provider Cache"
                               ,"C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History-journal"
                               ,"C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies"
                               ,"C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies-journal"
                               ,"C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies-journal"
        };

        foreach (string Datafile in chromedata)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Datafile))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(Datafile);
            }
            else
            {
                //File not there
            }
        }

        //Chache

        string chachefolder = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\default\\Cache";

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(chachefolder);

        if (Directory.Exists(chachefolder))
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                dir.Delete(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //cache folder does not exists
        }



    }
```